# How to set a div width with border in fix width div

Tags: html, css

How can i set a div `width` with `border:2px solid` the border comes out from parent div

**Note :- I want to fix in IE also.**

posting an example to better understating.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well just remove the width then (div as block element takes the full width automatically, so in this instance it is not needed) - or go read up on the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please add some more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` to that div. Check updated Snippet below

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
}

.two {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you need to add `display: block` to a div? A div is a block element already. Your code works because you have removed `width: 100%`

Comment: @Super User i will accept your answer because it's working and no need to write any css for IE.. Thanks buddy..

Answer (score 3):

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `box-sizing` property can slove your problem.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.two` like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

No fancy tricks. Note that adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to `*, *:before, *:after` as showed above may break other parts of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add box-sizing: border-box; to class="two" like this:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>

.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
 width: 100%;
 background: tomato;
 height: 40px;
}

.two {
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid;
 height: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```